# difference between prints in perl

Tags: perl, printing

silly question but to me they appear to be the same but I think there should be a difference. Is there any known difference between these 3 types of prints?

type1

```
print qq~ <td>....</td>~
```

type 2

```
print qq|<table>....</table>|
```

type 3

```
print <<EOT
<table>...</table>
EOT
```

Comment: See [quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) in Perl's doc. You can also `man perlop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type 1 and 2, [`Quote and Quote-like Operators`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

> While we usually think of quotes as literal values, in Perl they function as operators, providing various kinds of interpolating and pattern matching capabilities. Perl provides customary quote characters for these behaviors, but also provides a way for you to choose your quote character for any of them. In the following table, a {} represents **any pair of delimiters you choose**.

```
   Customary Generic     Meaning          Interpolates
        ''   q{}          Literal         no
        ""  qq{}          Literal         yes
        ``  qx{}          Command         yes*
            qw{}         Word list        no
        //   m{}       Pattern match      yes*
            qr{}          Pattern         yes*
             s{}{}      Substitution      yes*
            tr{}{}    Transliteration     no (but see below)
             y{}{}    Transliteration     no (but see below)
    <<EOF                 here-doc            yes*
* unless the delimiter is ''.
```

Type 3. [`Here-doc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Double-Quotes)

> Double quotes indicate that the text will be **interpolated** using exactly the same rules **as normal double quoted strings**.

```
   print <<EOF;
The price is $Price.
EOF
   print << "EOF"; # same as above
The price is $Price.
EOF
```